# Check the tuple each element has a value

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, performance-testing, template-meta-programming

I have a `std::tuple< std::optional<Args> ... >`, need to check that every element has a value.
I have implemented it with std::index_sequence. But I'm not sure this is the most efficient solution for fastest compile time.

```
using data_type = std::tuple< std::optional<Arg_1>, 
                              std::optional<Arg_2>,
                               //....
                              std::optional<Arg_n>  // where n > 40
                             >;

// My solution.
template <size_t ... indexes>
bool has_value_all_elements_impl(const data_type& tuple_data, std::index_sequence<indexes ...> ) {
       //I assume there O(n) lookup for each index in compile time. 
       // So total O(n^2) lookup for tuple ?
       return (std::get<indexes>(tuple_data).has_value() && ... ) ;
}

bool has_value_all_elements(data_type const& tuple_data)
{
     return has_value_all_elements_impl(
      tuple_data, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<data_type>::value>{});
}
```

Is there a more efficient O(n) algorithm for such problem?

Or is my solution already O(n) ?

Comment: This looks `O(n)` to me, what leads you to suspect it isn't?

Comment: Does this actually compile?  `std::get<indexes>(tuple_data).has_value() && ...` should have a `()` around it to make it a valid fold expression.  Other than that the code is already `O(N)` and should be as fast as you can get it.

Comment: @ 463035818_is_not_a_number . I'm interesting compile time performance. has_value will called n-times on runtime, its achieved.

Comment: Whether `std::get<N>` is `O(1)` compile-time or `O(N)` compile time depends on your STL implementation. This is an implementation detail, the c++ standard makes no statements about compilation performance.

Comment: Your  **EDIT** looks like an answer rather than part of the question. You can asnwer your own question by posting an answer below. On the other hand, editing the answer into the quesiton makes the question rather pointless.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::apply`?

Comment: @Artyer. I'm not sure, but std::apply used same algorithm, i.e std::make_index_sequence inside.

Answer (score 1):

I decided answer my own question.

Seems @chronial comment is right.

**source code** [on godbold](https://godbolt.org/z/WshrxK4fY) - Seems, it depends STL implementation. GCC stdlibc++ increased compile time is not linear. libc++ increased compile time is linear.

GCC:

```
    $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 11.1.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


 
$ time g++ -DARG_SIZE=10 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17     -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2

real    0m0.431s
user    0m0.384s
sys 0m0.047s


$ time g++ -DARG_SIZE=20 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17     -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2

real    0m0.507s
user    0m0.461s
sys 0m0.046s

$ time g++ -DARG_SIZE=40 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17     -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2

real    0m0.737s
user    0m0.666s
sys 0m0.071s

$ time g++ -DARG_SIZE=80 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17     -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2

real    0m2.030s
user    0m1.882s
sys 0m0.148s

$ time g++ -DARG_SIZE=160 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17     -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2

real    0m23.532s
user    0m23.216s
sys 0m0.312s

$ time g++ -DARG_SIZE=320 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17     -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2

real    10m40.392s
user    10m37.992s
sys 0m2.067s
```

CLang:

```
$ clang++ --version
Ubuntu clang version 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.5
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin


$ time clang++ -DARG_SIZE=10 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17  -stdlib=libc++   -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
example.cpp:36:15: warning: unused variable 'd' [-Wunused-variable]
    data_type d;
              ^
1 warning generated.

real    0m1.056s
user    0m0.667s
sys 0m0.066s

$ time clang++ -DARG_SIZE=20 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17  -stdlib=libc++   -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
example.cpp:36:15: warning: unused variable 'd' [-Wunused-variable]
    data_type d;
              ^
1 warning generated.

real    0m0.816s
user    0m0.764s
sys 0m0.048s

$ time clang++ -DARG_SIZE=40 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17  -stdlib=libc++   -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
example.cpp:36:15: warning: unused variable 'd' [-Wunused-variable]
    data_type d;
              ^
1 warning generated.

real    0m1.455s
user    0m0.985s
sys 0m0.095s

$ time clang++ -DARG_SIZE=80 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17  -stdlib=libc++   -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
example.cpp:36:15: warning: unused variable 'd' [-Wunused-variable]
    data_type d;
              ^
1 warning generated.

real    0m1.565s
user    0m1.484s
sys 0m0.067s

$ time clang++ -DARG_SIZE=160 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17  -stdlib=libc++   -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
example.cpp:36:15: warning: unused variable 'd' [-Wunused-variable]
    data_type d;
              ^
1 warning generated.

real    0m3.172s
user    0m2.410s
sys 0m0.080s

$ time clang++ -DARG_SIZE=320 -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" -std=c++17  -stdlib=libc++   -lpthread  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 -fbracket-depth=400
example.cpp:36:15: warning: unused variable 'd' [-Wunused-variable]
    data_type d;
              ^
1 warning generated.

real    0m4.576s
user    0m4.337s
sys 0m0.238s
```

Comment: Clang 12 seems a bit old to be interesting to me... (And which version of libc++ is that?)

Comment: Also, if the branchiness of your resulting codegen bothers you, it can be tamed down a bit with an intermediate `array`: https://godbolt.org/z/Gsvsbh7E6

Comment: @ildjarn. In your example for all fields has_value() will be evaluated, its cheap operation, but anywhere.

when fold expression && ..   evaluated until first has_value() == false expression.

Comment: Yes, I know; which means you have up to 320 branches in your demo, which may be highly undesirable for various reasons. Or it may not be an issue; just worth pointing out.